# how to send username or text with multiform data when sending files?

Tags: android, node.js

this is the client code i have right now to send images but i want to send current username with it. how do i send the username and how do i receive it on the server side

```
public class HttpUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

 private Context context;
 private String imgPath;
 int serverResponseCode = 0;


 public HttpUpload(Context context, String imgPath) {
super();
this.context = context;
this.imgPath = imgPath;
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

String upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.10.182:8080/uploadimage";


HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
File sourceFile = new File(imgPath);
if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
    Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
    return 0;
}
try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    Log.i("uploadFile", "" + fileInputStream);
    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",imgPath );
    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ imgPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

    //close the streams //
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();

    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
return null;
}
}
```

this is the server code i have to receive the file. how do i recieve the username in the server code

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var multer = require('multer');

**var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });**


var app = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var config = require("./config");
var requests = require("./model")(config);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/uploadimage',**upload.single('img')**,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.file);


});
```

Comment: You want to send the username and the image in the same request?

Comment: yes i want to send the username and image in the same request so when i  get the req.file i also get the req.body.username.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to get the current username, but have you tried `dos.write(username);`?  That seems like it's all you need to do based on the rest of the code

Comment: so if i just write dos.write(username); and then on the server side i do req.body.username will it work ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have all your code. I only asked if you tried it.

Comment: what more do u need ?

Comment: Personally, I don't know how multipart file uploads work, but I feel like writing a file boundary manually isn't the correct approach as there is probably a correct way to do it using some library..

Comment: i  tried what u said it doesnt work

Comment: You'll need to write a lineEnd after the file before you write the username. Then another lineEnd after the username and before the end boundary